# Appending values to my NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

OK, for some reason I'm getting a stupid error.

```
-(void) getAllRowsFromTableNamed: (NSString *) tableName {

    NSString *qsql = @"SELECT supplier from products";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2( db, [qsql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) ==
        SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *field1 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0);
            NSMutableString *field1Str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithUTF8String: field1];
            listofsuppliers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:field1Str, nil];
            NSLog(@"list of suppliers %@",listofsuppliers);
            [field1Str release];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
}
```

In my log I'm getting the following:

```
QueensWayInventory[13192:f803] list of suppliers ("(null)")
QueensWayInventory[13192:f803] list of suppliers ("(null)")
QueensWayInventory[13192:f803] list of suppliers (Dell)
QueensWayInventory[13192:f803] list of suppliers (Apple)
QueensWayInventory[13192:f803] list of suppliers (Apple)
QueensWayInventory[13192:f803] list of suppliers (Dell)
```

I want this instead:

```
QueensWayInventory[13192:f803] list of suppliers (
    Dell,
    Apple
)
```

It must be something very simple I'm doing wrong. When I create a static list I get it how I want it to be but not when I try to create a dynamic reading from a database.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
listofsuppliers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:field1Str, nil];
```

is your problem.

It throws away the old array and creates a new one with a single element.

Instead, before your loop you want:

```
listofsuppliers = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
```

I've used a Set instead of an Array since you want to include only a single copy of each element.

Then inside your loop:

```
[listofsuppliers addObject:field1Str];
```

Also note that there's no real need to create a mutable string here.

Comment: ok thanks alot, i got it using nsmutablearray. the problem was as u indicated. i jus had to put it outside of the loop and it worked. thanks alot (Y)

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to create your `NSMutableArray` **outside** the while loop. You are recreating it every iteration of the while loop, and when you print it to the console, it will always only have one value. Use `-appendObject:` to add each subsequent string value within the loop.
2. While there is nothing critical about creating a `NSMutableString` with the field1 utf8 string to then add to your array, usually it is better practice to create a non mutable `NSString`. Use a `NSMutableString` if you plan to manipulate the contents of that string.